# How to draw arrow in radial direction attached to circle using trigonometric functions in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am trying to to draw an arrow in the radial direction attached to a circle. The following code
draws such an arrow, but not at the desired angle (0.75 radians from the positive x-axis). How can this be fixed? I don't want to manually compute e.g. cos(0.75) and put it in the code, since I want to draw many arrows at different angles.

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
  \captionsetup{width=0.9\textwidth} 
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\tiny
      \draw (1,1) circle (0.5 cm);
      \draw[->] ({1+0.5*cos(0.75)},{1+0.5*sin(0.75)}) -- ({1+1.4*cos(0.75)},{1+1.4*sin(0.75)});      
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: For polar coordinates use (deg(0.75): 0.5)+(1,1), or ($(1,1)+(deg(0.75):0.5)$) with calc tikzlibrary.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks for your comment! The problem could be solved by adding [trig format=rad].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

It is not entirely clear, what is the problem. Calculation of trigonometric function when angles are given in radians? If this is case, than you can left their calculation to macro `trig format=rad`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
polar coordinates:

\begin{tikzpicture}[trig format=rad]
\draw (1,1) circle (0.5 cm);
     \draw[->] (1,1) ++ (0.75:0.5) -- ++ (0.75:0.9);
\end{tikzpicture}

cartesian coordinates:

\begin{tikzpicture}[trig format=rad]
    \draw[red] (1,1) circle (0.5 cm);
    \draw[red, ->] ({1+0.5*cos(0.75)},{1+0.5*sin(0.75)}) -- ({1+1.4*cos(0.75)},{1+1.4*sin(0.75)});
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this what you after?

Comment: Thanks! The problem was that I did not put [trig format=rad] (I thought it was radians by default). Hence the arrow was at such a small angle that I didn't see it was rotated at all.